# Convert email body to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I'm working on something that uses regex to search something from an email, which is fetched via imaplib module. Right now I can't get it to work, even after using `str()` function.

```
result, data = mail.fetch(x, '(RFC822)')
eemail = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
print(str(eemail))
```

trying to regex it:

```
print(re.search("button", eemail))
```

Regex gives me no matches even after making the email a string object.

Comment: Typically the "body" will be a MIME structure which contains a hierarchy of body parts, some of which will need decoding before you can search. Parse into an `email` object and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
import imaplib
import email
import re

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
mail.login(FROM_EMAIL,FROM_PWD)
mail.select('inbox')

status, response = mail.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
unread_msg_nums = response[0].split()

for e_id in unread_msg_nums:
    _, response = mail.fetch(e_id, '(UID BODY[TEXT])')
    b = email.message_from_string(response[0][1])
    if b.is_multipart():
        for payload in b.get_payload(decode=True):
            print(re.search("button", payload.get_payload(decode=True)))
    else:
        print(re.search("button", b.get_payload(decode=True)))
```